# How many entries can Sobipro handle?

Tags: joomla3.0, sobipro

How many entries can sobipro handle. I'd like to use this so my clients real estate clients can post up their business. Currently we have a little over 10,000 business with one image each and contact info.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of business do you work for?

Comment: We manage real estate business and setup networking events. We currently have 10,000 clients that come to our events or correspond with us. We currently do not have an online database setup for this and was pointed towards sobipro.

Answer (score 0):

SobiPro  multi directory extension is free so I say give it a shot to see if it has enough memory for those 10,000 businesses -https://www.sigsiu.net/download/sobipro.